# Using the trapezoidal rule for the Maxwell-Boltzman function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, applications

### Background

I approached my physics professor with question 1 from [this LibreTexts resource.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Kinetics/03%3A_Rate_Laws/3.01%3A_Gas_Phase_Kinetics/3.1.02%3A_Maxwell-Boltzmann_Distributions#:) (at the bottom of the page), to better understand the material via self-study.

> **Question**
>
> Using the Maxwell-Boltzman function, calculate the fraction of argon gas molecules with a speed of $305\ \text{m}/\text{s}$ at $500\ \text{K}$.
>
> **My attempt**
>
> We have argon molecules in the air at $500\ \text{K}$ and we'd like to know fraction of the gas molecules with a speed of $305 \text{m}/\text{s}$. So, we have
>
> - $M=39.948 \ \text{g/mol}=0.039948\ \text{kg/mol}$
> - $R=8.3145\ \text{J/mol}\cdot K (\text{as in SI units, the real gas constant, }\ R, \text{is equal to }\ 8.3145 \text{J/mol}\cdot K)$.
> - $J=\text{Kg}\cdot\text{m}^2/\text{s}^2$
> - $T=500\ \text{K}$
>
> $$\int^{305.5}_{304.5} 4\pi \left(\frac{0.039948}{((2\pi)8.3145)500}\right)^{3/2}x^2\exp\left(-\frac{0.039948x^2}{(2\times 8.3145)500}\right)dx=0.00141405\ \square$$

My professor mentioned that I was correct in assuming that as we only want the atom with speed of $305 \text{m/s}$, the limits should be $304.5 - 305.5$. However, since this is such a small interval, we can just approximate the area under the curve with a simple rectangle with height $f(305)$ and width $1$. No integration is necessary.

### My Attempt

$$\int^b_a f(x)dx \approx \Delta x\left(\frac{y_0}{2}+y_1+y_2+y_3+\cdots+\frac{y_0}{2}\right)$$
where $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$. We have $a=304.5, b=305.5, n=4$, and

$$y=4\pi \left(\frac{0.039948}{((2\pi)8.3145)500}\right)^{3/2}x^2\exp\left(-\frac{0.039948x^2}{(2\times 8.3145)500}\right)$$

Therefore,
$$\Delta x=\frac{305.5-304.5}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$$
We divide the interval $[304.5,305.5]$ into $n=4$ subintervals of the length $\Delta x=\frac{1}{4},$ with the following endpoints: $a=304.5,\frac{1}{4}, 0, \frac{3}{4}, 305.5=b.$

Now, we just evaluate the function at these endpoints
\begin{align*}
y_0&=f(a)=f(304.5)=0.00141148\\
y_1&=f(a+\Delta x)=f(304.75)=0.00141277\\
y_2&=f(a+\Delta 2x)=f(305)=0.00141405\\
y_3&=f(a+\Delta 3x)=f(305.25)=0.00141533\\
y_4&=f(a+\Delta 4x)=f(305.5)=0.00141661\\
\end{align*}

So, we have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\times0.00141148+0.00141277+0.00141405+0.00141533+\frac{1}{2}\times0.00141661\right)\\
&\approx 0.00141404875\\
\end{align*}

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
from math import sin, pi

f=lambda x: (4*np.pi)*(0.039948/(((2*np.pi)*8.3145)*500))**(3/2)*x**2*np.exp((-0.039948*x**2)/((2*8.3145)*500))
a=304.5
b=305.5
n=4
h=(b-a)/n
S=0.5*(f(a)+f(b))
for i in range(1,n):
    S+=f(a+i*h)
Integral=h*S
print('Integral=%f' %Integral)

## Integral=0.001414
```

The solutions appear to match, but is this method succinct? Can I improve this computation?

Comment: Using [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint%5E%7B305.5%7D_%7B304.5%7D+4%5Cpi+%28%5Cfrac%7B0.039948%7D%7B%28%282%5Cpi%298.3145%29500%7D%29%5E%7B3%2F2%7Dx%5E2%5Cexp%28-%5Cfrac%7B0.039948x%5E2%7D%7B%282%5Ccdot+8.3145%29500%7D%29dx) a numeric integration (black box) finds $0.00141405$ and so does the simple method of your professor. This shows that the trapezoidal method is overkill in that case of a nearly constant function on the interval.